# css tree folders list with jquery progress bar

Tags: jquery, css, list, html, tree

I have a tree of folders and I want to add a progress bar next to the folder name which is also an anchor. The progress bar div section is the jQuery UI progress bar div.

The `pblabel` element should seat on top of the progress bar. The bar element is the progress bar itself with a variable width.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="" style="display: inline;">test</a>
    <div id="progressbar" style="display: inline; height: 2em; background: white;">
      <div id="pblabel" style="position: absolute">progress</div>
      <div id="bar" style="display: inline; background: blue; width: 30%; height: 100%;></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can see the anchor element fine with the `pblabel` element next to it. I don't see the blue bar element or the white background of the progressbar element.

Comment: If it's just a matter of CSS you might be better off asking this on doctype. Either way, could we see a screenshot or a link to a live demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="bar" style="display: inline; background: blue; width: 30%; height: 100%;></div>
```

This line is missing a `"` before the `>`. Besides that the reason you are not seeing the blue bar is that it has a width of 30% **and** is `inline` (and it is also empty). `inline` means that it will use as few space as possible; for that reason a `width` is meaningless for `inline` elements.

Since the div is empty (there is nothing inside) and is inline its width will be 0 and you won't see it.